# Adding an SSD to dual boot environment to make a triple boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

To clarify based on comments below, I installed Windows onto a new disk and now I want to be able to boot from that disk using gGrub installed on a different disk. Do I need to change the way I install Windows, or do I need to do something clever with grub?

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on the same HDD working well on a dual boot.

I added an SSD, changed BIOS boot order and installed a 'lite' version of Windows 7 on the SSD. I am doing project work and need a version with no antivirus, etc. Now I have changed the BIOS boot order back so I get my grub menu. I want to add an entry to that will allow me to boot the lite drive from grub instead of having to switch the BIOS back and forward every time. I do not want to reinstall Ubuntu or my main Windows 7, but I will consider redoing the 'lite' version if that will help me achieve what I am looking for.

I have a feeling that this should be pretty easy, but I am not seeing it. The obvious solution of running `grub-update` is not seeing the Windows 8 installation. In the `fdisk` listing below, `/sda` is my working dual boot. `/sbd` is my SSD (note the error reported), `/sd`c is my shared storage drive and `/sdd` is my removable backup disk.

```
paul@Pauls-box:~$ sudo fdisk -l 
[sudo] password for paul: 

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x7535f3a5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63      417689      208813+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          417690  1441520064   720551187+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1441521662  1953523711   256001025    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1441521664  1480583167    19530752   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1480585216  1544583167    31998976   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7      1544585216  1953521663   204468224   83  Linux

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30282 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdc: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4228d32c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  2930272255  1465135104    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000194400256 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121600 cylinders, total 1953504688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8d81c186

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *          64  1953499903   976749920    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Windows only installs to gpt drives with UEFI boot. And only installs ot MBR(msdos) partitioned drives with BIOS boot mode. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible, so once you start booting or are at grub menu, you cannot switch. So you can only boot from UEFI menu or perhaps one time boot key. You can reinstall in BIOS boot mode, but need to fully erase gpt with fixparts as Windows does not. And make sure to have SSD set as boot in BIOS during Windows install. Normally Windows only installs all boot files for all Windwos installs to one drive and one partition with the boot flag.

Answer (score -1):

have you red the comment in your disk listing ?
"GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted."

Probably, it's teh problem.